# Typescript ignores node_module's tsconfig

Tags: typescript

In my project, in `tsconfig.json` I have selected the option `strict=true` (enable all strict type checking options).

When I add `import { sso } from 'node-expose-sspi';` I get approximately 60 errors from tsc.

For example:
`src/sso/auth.ts line 88 waitForReleased accepts string but cookieToken is string | undefined`

I noticed, in node-expose-sspi tsconfig there is only `noImplicitAny=true`, which implies other strict checks options to be false. Because of that running tsc directly in node-expose-sspi folder produces no error but it fails from my project folder.

But why does typescript compiler ignore module specific tsconfig.json?

Can I somehow force top level tsc to use `./node_modules/xxx/tsconfig.json` when compiling xxx module?

Edit:

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,

    "strict": true,

    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,

    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

And server.ts:

```js
import express = require('express');
import { sso } from 'node-expose-sspi';

const app = express();

app.use(sso.auth());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.json({
    sso: req.sso,
  });
});

app.listen(3001, () => console.log('Server started on port 3001'));
```

Edit: I have changed the server.ts to exact copy of exaple from [node-expose-sspi](https://github.com/jlguenego/node-expose-sspi/blob/HEAD/doc/typescript.md).

Sorry, I made mistake in initial question.
When I use `const { sso } = require('node-expose-sspi');` I do not get errors from typescript.
In fact, TS completely ignores this module and I get error in:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.json({
    sso: req.sso,
  });
});
```

In line `req.sso`: `Property 'sso' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.`

But, as soon as I change to `import { sso } from "node-expose-sspi";` I get 62 errors related to module.

Comment: Is it in a react project?

Comment: No, just node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up importing sspi with `const { sso } = require('node-expose-sspi');`. This way `typescript` does not check this module.
The only drawback is that `typescript` does not recognise `sso` in `request`. That is not a big problem for me. I need sso only to get username in intranet application.
Therefore I just added `@ts-ignore` before problematic line.

```
//@ts-ignore
const username = request.sso.user.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in `tsconfig` file

```
"exclude": [
 "node_modules"
]
```

Comment: `exclude` does not work when you import module in ts file.